# How to place grid cell in check board form where every white cell is empty

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07unL.png) How to create css grid layout as given in image link.
I want to add empty space in blank area and cell div element at blue area.

this is how much i am able to achieve.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .grid-contaienr {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 120px 100px;
        grid-auto-rows: ;
    }

    .cell {
        background-color: aqua;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgb(71, 71, 71) inset;
    }

    .cell:nth-child(3n) {
        grid-column: 2;
    }


    .cell:nth-child(3n+1) {
        grid-column: 2;
    }

    .cell:nth-child(3n) {
        grid-column: auto/span 2;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="grid-contaienr">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
    <div class="cell">9</div>
    <div class="cell">10</div>
    <div class="cell">11</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell">13</div>
    <div class="cell">14</div>
    <div class="cell">15</div>
    <div class="cell">16</div>
    <div class="cell">17</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to used grid-area property as my html content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `display: grid` to create a grid structure in css. You can read more here [CSS_Grid_Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
.container {
   display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
  grid-row: auto auto;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container div:nth-child(2),
.container div:nth-child(3),
.container div:nth-child(6),
.container div:nth-child(7){
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="cell">1</div>
      <div class="cell">2</div>
      <div class="cell">3</div>
      <div class="cell">4</div>
      <div class="cell">5</div>
      <div class="cell">6</div>
      <div class="cell">7</div>
      <div class="cell">8</div>
    </div>
```

EDIT: Added blue background to alternate divs

Comment: but cell are not placed according to given image. i want cell to be in blue color not in linear order and white part should be empty

Comment: Edited my answer. The CSS is added to fix number of boxes. To make it dynamic, you may need to use JavaScript